# how to structure a mysql table in order to stress the database as less as possible (with using hibernate)

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, database-design

I've got one question about the structure of a database when using hibernate.

I have to save information (one number) for every day in the database.
Very often I need to select the information for a whole month.

When Ive got a table with (date, information), then I have to do up to 31 selects to get the data for one month. As I do this very often, it stresses the database.

Now I thought of writing the whole information (31 numbers) into a MONTH-table, with a column "month" and another column "information", where I put in all the numbers separated by a ";". Then I would only have to do one select. But I would have to split up the datarecord in order to get the numbers (split up at every ";").

So maybe, another solution would be a MONTH-Table, with 32 columns (month and 1 to 31). the 1 to 31 columns would be tinyints and I would store the numbers in it.
I would have to make one select to get the data from each month and I would not have to split up the datarecord but could request the data per column (I use hibernate)

Does this last solution have any disadvantages I didnt think of? :-) Would you recommend another solution?

[EDIT]
Thanks for your help. This was the data structure before:

```
create table CLIENTS_DATA (
client_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
datum date NOT NULL, 
information tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default 0, 
** additional informations **
primary key(client_id, datum),
foreign key(client_id) references clients(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) 
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and here did I now store the information for a whole month in:

```
create table CLIENTS_MONTHLY_INFORMATIONS (
client_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
datum date NOT NULL,
i1 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i2 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i3 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i4 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i5 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i6 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i7 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i8 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i9 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i10 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i11 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i12 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i13 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i14 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i15 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i16 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i17 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i18 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i19 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i20 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i21 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i22 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i23 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i24 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i25 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i26 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i27 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i28 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i29 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i30 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
i31 tinyint NOT NULL default 0,
average float UNSIGNED,
primary key(client_id, datum),
foreign key(client_id) references clients(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) 
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

a query for the second table would be:

```
public ClientsMonthlyInformations getClientsMonthlyInformationsByIdAndDate(int uid, Date datum) {

ClientsMonthlyInformations cmi = (ClientsMonthlyInformations) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from ClientsMonthlyInformations clientsmonthlyinformations where clientsmonthlyinformations.clients.id=:clientsid and clientsmonthlyinformations.datum=:date").setParameter("clientsid", uid).setParameter("date", datum).uniqueResult();

return cmi;
}
```

to get data from the first table I use the same entry, but of course ClientsData instead of ClientsMonthlyInformation. You are correct, I could create a query to get 31-Datarecords, that means 31 Hibernate-Objects. I don't know why I thought that doing one select on 31 rows to get 31 objects would be bad.

Comment: Why don't you just have a column that has the date? You can still perform selects based on the value of the date column.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your table structure  and your `SELECT` queries. It somehow rings a bad bell when I read that you query up to 31 time per month, something indicates a bad design there as you should be able to do that in 1 query.

Answer (score 1):

> have to do up to 31 selects to get the data for one month. As I do this very often, it stresses the database

Define often? How many days have you currently got? Unless it's more than 20 times per second there shouldn't be **any** measurable impact in the database.

> Now I thought of writing the whole information (31 numbers) into a MONTH-table

That's a really dumb idea and is not going to solve the problem.

If you have to issue 31 selects to fetch a months data then you **really** need to learn more about querying databases.

Without knowing what your table structure is nor what the output format you require is, it's not possible to provide a specific solution, but you might consider:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%Y-%m'), GROUP_CONCAT(metric)
 FROM (
     SELECT a.date, a.metric
     FROM your_table a
     WHERE a.date>20110101000000
     ORDER BY a.date
 )
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%Y-%m');
```

(assuming you want the output in a denormalised structure - and are absolutely sure there are no missing/duplicate days)

Comment: as I wrote above, I was maybe wrong. I put my table structure above. I possibly could query the 31 informations I need with one select, thats true. I would get then 31 Hibernate Objects. I dont know, but I somehow thought that wouldnt be a good idea. - well, and its not more than 20 times per second - not now! but why not make the database as perfect as possible, in the future there may be a lot more selects.